# JAMES apache mail server multiple e-mail aliases

Tags: apache-2.2, alias, email-server

Is it possible (and how) to add multiple e-mail aliases for a single mail account on [JAMES mail server](http://james.apache.org/)?

I have tried using `setalias` to create an alias as shown [here](http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/james/james.html#install_2.2.0), but from what I've seen each subsequent call to `setalias` overrides the previous call and leaves only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing this with the forward mailet:

```
<mailet match="RecipientIs=help@kunagi.org" class="Forward">
    <forwardto>support@kunagi.org</forwardto>
</mailet>
```

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot. I added the mailet as you described to `\apps\james\SAR-INF\config.xml`. I also needed to set `enableForwarding` to `true`, and restarted the JAMES service.